# Multi GPU with GPU Passthrough Setup

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kvm-virtualization, gpu

I am having trouble setting up multi GPU, with the goal of having GPU passthrough to a KVM Windows 10 install.

I have a relatively old MB, but it appears to support IOMMU.  I have purchased a very cheap video card (Geforce 710) to act as the host GPU while I pass through a beefier GPU to the VM.  Trouble is, I get no video out on the 710 while the beefy GPU is installed.  When I go through the steps to configure IOMMU at the kernel level, the primary display freezes at boot (where you would expect it to), but the 710 still doesn't take over.

Do I need to recompile video drivers or something with the new card before I engage the IOMMU configuration for the VM?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
master@HomeServer:~$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Comment: This is a very complex topic, especially when you run into issues. I can recommend this guide here: https://mathiashueber.com/ I suggest you start with a fresh installation just to make sure that no applications interfere with each other. With a little bit of luck the guide will help you through the steps. No recompilation of drivers should be needed

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Incidentally the exact same GPU, a 710 while following the mathiashueber.com guide with a fresh installation.

Answer (score 3):

You've likely already solved this issue, or moved on, but for anyone else who lands here with the same problem as I did I'll go through the steps I took to resolve it.

The solution was to tell X.Org Server which GPU to target by setting the BusID of the GPU that isn't being used for passthrough in the xorg.conf.

Find the BusID of the GPU that is intended to be used as your primary display.

```
lspci | grep NVIDIA
```

> **03:00.0** VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)

Generate an xorg.config with the latest settings.

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Modify xorg.conf.

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Update the Device section to include a reference to the BusID of the GPU that is to be used as the display. In my case the BusID was **03:00.0** so I updated the Device section of my xorg.conf as follows.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:3@0:0:0"
EndSection
```

In your case your BusID is **05:00.0**, so modifying your xorg.conf as below should fix your issue.

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier     "nvidia"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BusID          "PCI:5@0:0:0"
    EndSection
```

I found these useful when trying to determine how to format the BusID in the xorg.conf.

[Xorg.conf Documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading10)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585910/setting-busid-in-xorg-conf

Comment: Thanks. I did end up doing exactly this, and that got video to display in X on the correct gpu. However, because the other gpu was the "boot" gpu, the virt driver wasn't fully able to take control. So tty1 consoles still would output to the wrong gpu. Only way I solved it was to put the 710 in the primary gpu slot physically, and run the passthrough gpu in a second pcie slot.

Comment: I believe that's the issue I am now experiencing. The GPU seems to be passed through successfully however when Nvidia drivers are loaded Win10 freezes and won't reboot until the passed through card is removed. Unfortunately there are too many devices in the same IOMMU group as the other slot.

Comment: Finally cracked it without swapping slots. Added 'video=efifb:off' to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and rebooted the machine with no monitor connected to the passed through card.

Comment: Note that the BusID string in xorg.conf is specified in decimal whereas lspci returns it in hexidecimal. So the `lspci` command returned my GPU as being at `a1:00.0`, in xorg.conf this translated to a BusID of `"PCI:161:0:0"` because the hexadecimal number a1 is 161 in decimal.